# How to import and export data from and to primavera

Tags: c#, sql-server, primavera

We have project management software developed in .Net 4.0 and using Sql Server.
We want to establish bidirectional communication with Primavera.

How is this done, and where to start?

Comment: How to integrate the data in the project management database with external databases and applications?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Primavera APIs to do this for you . 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16281_01/Technical_Documentation/Integration_API/ProgrammerReference.html

Comment: Thank you jetty for this reference. Have you run any sample on this? How do we get data from primavera database?